# Flask-Security modify register form post validation

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms, flask-security

I am using Flask-WTF and WTForms and I have a form which looks like this:

```
class RegForm(ConfirmRegisterForm):
    code = TextField('Invite Code', [Required(), validate_code])
```

I am using Flask-Security and this is my registration form. On my model, there is a column called `code_id` which is a `ForeignKey` field. I want to remove the `code` field from the form and add a `code_id` field after my validator is run, so that I send a integer foreign key instead of a string code to my model during registration. I could modify the form inside the validator, but that would only modify an instance of the form from what I know, and it wouldn't have an effect on the main form. Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could try to use coerce=int.